# How to change Python version in which modules get installed?

Tags: python, module, version

I'm trying to install Python-Twitch for Python 3.4.  I have both 3.4 and 3.5 installed on my computer, and in command prompt I do this:

```
python --version
```

Where it gives me Python 3.5.x.  Then:

```
set PATH=C:\Python34\;%PATH%
```

And python --version will then read Python 3.4.x.

Once I do 'pip install python-twitch', it installs it to the Python 3.5 Lib/Site-Packages folder.  How would I get this over to 3.4?

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: You have multiple pips and it is the version of pip that controls which python the library gets installed. You need to select the correct pip. Type pip on your console and hit tab and you shall see multiple pip's.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was already answered: [pip: dealing with multiple Python versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions)

Since version 0.8, Pip supports pip-{version}. You can use it the same as easy_install-{version}:

```
$ pip-2.5 install myfoopackage
$ pip-2.6 install otherpackage
$ pip-2.7 install mybarpackage
```

EDIT: pip changed its schema to use pipVERSION instead of pip-VERSION in version 1.5. You should use the following if you have pip >= 1.5:

```
$ pip2.6 install otherpackage
$ pip2.7 install mybarpackage
```

Check https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/1053 for more details